# Multi-level design definition in a custom control

Tags: xpages, custom-controls

[image: Properties]

I have a custom control defined that has multi-level Property Definition:
I am trying to write my Design Definition. I can easily access the textcenter and centerblock properties like this:

```
Center text = <%=this.textcenter %>
Center block = <%=this.centerblock %>
```

However, I am not able to access the propeties that are in the width and offset folders in my Design Definition.
I tried

```
Column Offset xs= <%=this.offset.xs%>
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Hmm could be a bug. If i enable "Allow multiple instances" on the group, then this will work: `<%=this.offset[0].xs%>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, this is a bug in the core code (i.e. not fixable in an extlib release). The code only handles custom properties containing a String/primitive or Collections, so it doesn't handle nested objects that aren't collections.

As I suggested you can work around this by changing your custom group to "allow multiple instances" and referencing it in the design definition. You just need to be careful to handle the case when no property has been defined:

```
Column Offset xs= <%= (null != this.offset && this.offset.length > 0 ? this.offset[0].xs : 'default') %>
```

Not ideal, but gets around the problem for now.

Comment: I enabled the allow multiple instances on the width group, and now I get this error: 

"Error processing 'Design Definition' markup for Custom control: Unknown indexed property [0]"

Comment: Ah, that happens if you leave width prop undefined when adding the CC to an XPage. Trying to see if there's a way around that

Comment: I've updated my snippet for the design definition, so that it can handle the case that no property has been defined. Any better?

Comment: The only problem is that, the Design Definition does not update automaticaly if I change the values of the custom properties.

Comment: Indeed, seems to require closing the xpage and reopening to refresh to the latest